# Convert OpenGL 4x4 matrix to rotation angles

Tags: xcode, opengl, matrix, rotation

I am extracting in OpenGL the Model Matrix with
glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (float*)x)

And would like to extract from the resulting 4x4 matrix the x,y and z axis rotations. How Can I do that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Look at this SOQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766284/opengl-position-and-orientation-from-modelview-matrix

Comment: Thanks, I tried to apply the script in it, but the result is not really correct. E.g. I set to OpenGL xyz rot = [80,80,80] and the script in your link returns me [-85,70,-85]. Any idea why this could be ? Thanks !

Comment: the order of rotations are very important...xyz might have to be applied zyx (maybe) usually they are called euler angles  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles and applied heading-pitch-roll wise

Comment: The bad thing (or one bad thing) with euler angles is, that everybody uses different conventions (axes and their ordering) and implicitly assumes his convention to be the standard, so you should always carefully check, which of the possible 12 conventions you and the others are using.

Answer (score 3):

First you should know, that x,y,z axis rotations, called Euler Angles suffer from serious numerical problems. Also they're not unambigous. So either you store a rotation angle and the rotation axis, thus effectively forming a quaternion in disguise, or you stick with the full rotation matrix.

Find the quaternion from a rotation matrix is called an eigenvalue problem. Technically you're determining the eigenvector of the rotation matrix, which is the axis and the magnitude designates the angle.

Comment: Why I would it like, is because I store my angles in 3 variables and in my draw function of OpenGL, I perform 3x glRotate on these angles. Now I would like to rotate further on one of these 3 axis, so I use a additional time the glRotate, and reask the matrix to the system to re-store my new rotation angle. Is there a nicer way to do that ?

Comment: @Laurent Crivello: Please don't store rotations as Euler angles, for chaos and madness awaits you at their end. Instead store the rotation as a single quaternion. Further rotations are applied by multiplying onto that quaternion. It's trivial to convert a quaternion into a rotation matrix which can be applied onto the OpenGL matrix stack with glMultMatrix. Furthermore you should not mistreat OpenGL as a math library; OpenGL-3 removed all matrix manipulation functions, requiring the user to keep track of matrices himself. This is to keep people from what you're doing.

Comment: So basically I should not keep my x,y,z as separate angles in an array and use glRotate commands, but rather keep a 3x3 rotation matrix and multiply it by the current matrix, right ?

Comment: @Laurent Crivello: Yes, either that, or use a quarternion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a CAD-like app, so I understand your problem, we 'in the business' know how awful Euler angles are for linear transformations - but the end-user finds them far more intuitive than matrices or quaternions.

For my app I interpreted Ken Shoemake's wonderful algorithm, it's one of the very few that support arbitrary rotation orders.  It's from '93, so it's in pure C code - not for the faint hearted!

http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/euler_angle/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you what you're after.

```
final double roll = Math.atan2(2 * (quat.getW() * quat.getX() + quat.getY() * quat.getZ()),
            1 - 2 * (quat.getX() * quat.getX() + quat.getY() * quat.getY()));
final double pitch = Math.asin(2 * (quat.getW() * quat.getY() - quat.getZ() * quat.getY()));
final double yaw = Math.atan2(2 * (quat.getW() * quat.getZ() + quat.getX() * quat.getY()), 1 - 2 * (quat.getY()
            * quat.getY() + quat.getZ() * quat.getZ()));
```

I use this as a utility function to print out camera angles when I'm using SLERP to interpolate between 2 quaternions that I've derived from 2 4x4 matrices (i.e. camera movement between 2 3D points).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However my quaternion is a 4x4 matrix, where the first 3x3 is used for rotation. However I can't retrieve in your code the mapping between mat[0-1-2 / 4-5-6 / 8-9-10] and the getX,Y,Z or W. Any hint for me ? Thanks !

Comment: If you're using Java and the vecmath library, you can create a quaternion by `Quat4d quaternion = new Quat4d(); quaternion.set(yourMatrix);`.